# SQL Plus command not found

Tags: software-installation, sql

I downloaded instant-client zip directories for basic Linux, sqlplus and for SDK and unzipped them in `opt/oracle`.Then I added to my .bashrc file to follows:

```
export PATH=:$PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5
```

I have sqlplus executable in `/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5`.When I run ./sqlplus from home I get command not found. It however opens when I go to its'
directory and run `./sqlplus` but prompts me for username-password which I do not know since this is the first time I am starting?Two questions :

1. How can I run using `sqlplus` rather than `./sqlplus` and that too if I want to do so from any where(not just that subdirectory)?
2. I do not know username or password. Tried using / as sysdba but not working.What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

Ad1. to be able to use sqlplus from anywhere you can link it with:

`ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus`

and then it should be available from anywhere since /usr/bin is already in your `PATH`

Ad 2. Instant client is just client. You need to install the oracle database to set up username and password during the database installation process.